# Using secureTextInput with multiple TextInput fields causes UI problems on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

I have two secureTextEntry fields, one for password and one for retype-password.  Testing this on iOS emulator I get the jumping behaviour demonstrated in [this video](https://youtu.be/95kjJet4Q6Y).

If I turn off secureTextEntry in just the second password field, the jumping behaviour stops, and everything works normally.

Has anybody else seen this or know why it's happening?

Relevant code snippets below:

```
<TextInput
  placeholder="Password"
  value={passwordVal}
  onChangeText={setPasswordValue}
  secureTextEntry={true}
/>
Password
<TextInput/>

<TextInput
  placeholder="Retype Password"
  value={retypeVal}
  onChangeText={setRetypeVal}
  secureTextEntry={true}
/>
Retype Password
<TextInput/>
```

Comment: I have the same problem ... Still not fixed as I see ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is related to `secureTextEntry`. Maybe you are using some custom third-party components that they are causing this problem.